# Open local text file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am trying to write a JavaScript program that reads a local txt file and Safes the Content into an Array. (just an offline JavaScript)
I already tried many different methods, but None of them is working:

The activeXObject solution is not working.
Server based php Code is not working.
FileReader API is not working.

Comment: Possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file

Comment: I also saw this link above and tried all the possibilities, but None of them is working for me!!

Comment: why is there a css tag?

Comment: are you trying to write a web page that reads a file from an end users computer without any interaction from the user? if so, you can't do that. You can only read a file the user wishes you to read (drag/drop or file picker type thing)

Comment: I'm trying to read a local text file only by having the filepath. Is that not possible in JavaScript? :/

Comment: Basically when i click a specific button on the html page, the program should read the Content of a .txt file in an Array in the Background just to have some Information (that i Need).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - read local text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file)

Comment: You need to tell us more about your environment. Is your code running in a browser, on a server (node.js), or some other environment?

Comment: my Code is running in a browser. I'm working on a file Manager and i came to the solution that reading a Textfile, where some paths are saved, is the best Option.

Comment: But if you have a non-server-based solution for reading all file-names in a local Directory on my PC (preferable with javascript) and print them out on the html page..... then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readFile(file){

        if(file.files && file.files[0]){
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {  
                var input = e.target.result;
                var output = input.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /\@/).join("\n");

                document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = output;
            };
            reader.readAsText(file.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```